# Only display an inline "add object" field if no objects exist

Tags: django

In my Django application, I have a model, X. It has a related/helper model Y, which contains some extra info about it. Instances of Y are bound to their Xs with a `ForeignKey` (that is, `Y` contains a `models.ForeignKey(X)`).

I also have this code in my `admin.py`:

```
class YInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Y
    extra = 1
```

This works fine, but the inline field for adding a new Y is *always* displayed: when adding a new X, and when editing an existing X which already has some Ys bound to it. I would like to show the field only if X has no Ys bound to it yet (either because it's being created or because no Ys were assigned to it previously). If we're editing an X which already contains some Ys, the inline should not be displayed; the user will use the "Add another Y" button if they wish to add one.

How can I achieve this? I'm using the latest stable version of Django, 1.10 at the time of writing.

Comment: Did the below answer worked for your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [get_extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.get_extra) method of the `YInline` class, like this:

```
class YInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Y
    # extra is remove here, is overidden below

    def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # obj is the parent model, for your case X.
        # If X has no Y attribute (thus X is created), return 1 extra inline
        # If X exists, but has null Y's, return 1 extra inline
        if not hasattr(obj, '<related_name_here>') or not obj.<related_name_here>.exists():
            return 1
        # If X exists and has some pre-saved Y's, return 0 extra inlines
        return 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem. Nice to know there are people who know these dusty corners of Django.

Comment: I got the error '<Related_Model_Name>' object has no attribute 'exists'. Removing the `or not obj.<related_name_here>.exists()` part of the conditional statement fixes it and the code works as intended. Thanks.